# I can't find where my css link color is coming from. Any clues?

Tags: css, colors

I have a link that shows up white and gray for "a" and "a:hover".  And Firebug says that is what is specified in my CSS file.  But it isn't what is in there and I can't find where it might be being overridden.  Any clues for me?

Below is what Firebug and other browser helpers report:

```
media="screen"
#header-area a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But this is what is in the CSS file:

```
media="screen"
#header-area a {
  color: #005dcc;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I also did a search through the source code of the entire site for "#eeeeee" and only found two incidences in 209 files and they were for border colors.

I also discovered that this problem is only found in the header.php portion of my site.

Does anyone have a clue for me as to what might be setting this color?

Comment: Magic. ok kidding. Firebug should tell you the location of the definition--which file, line number, etc... if it's pointing to a file you're sure you've edited and saved, clear the cache.

Comment: also, look in conditional stylesheets, like if you have different stylesheets for print and screen. (don't forget to check the header file too, I often find out that styles are declared within `<style>` tags that drive me crazy). and if it wordpress, see custom style option in theme options (those can thrown dynamically and often are hard to find). hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching for #eee.